# Regarding the exchange of gluons between quarks and the Pauli exclusion principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, standard-model

When the quarks in a hadron exchange gluons, for a tiny fraction of a second two of the quarks in the hadron have the same colour charge, thus violating the Pauli exclusion principle. Does this mean that quantum chromodynamics is incorrect?

Comment: This is as inflammatory a rhetorical question as the wildest of gonzo popular science reporting, of which there is a lot making the rounds... No, this is not the nail in the coffin of QCD. A mutating Red quark is Pauli-antisymmetrized with the nascent Red quark that picks up the relay gluon, but they don't have the same momentum to yield a null operator quark-quadrilinear-cum-gluon, in color singlet. Write it down and study it. Where did this  deeply flawed picture come from?

Comment: see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html , the gluon is many colored.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Could you please explain this? I am only 11.

Comment: The metaphor of gluon exchange is code language for a quantum amplitude and does not mean you have coexisting quarks excluding each other. the theory is fine.